# не передается переменная из контроллера в шаблон

Tags: php, laravel

передаю переменную из контроллера во вью, но она не передается
вот контроллер

```php
public function AllDuels()
    {
        $allDuels = Duels::all();
        return view('home', ['allDuels'=>$allDuels]);
    }
```

вью

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <div class="duels">
                        <h5>Сейчас в дуэли:</h5><br>
                            @foreach($allDuels as $duel)
                                <a href="{{ route('showOneDuel', $duel->nameDuel) }}">{{ $duel->name }}</a><br>
                            @endforeach
                    </div>
```

роутер

```php
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\DuelsController::class, 'AllDuels'])->name('AllDuels');
```

выдает ошибку Undefined variable $AllDuels

Comment: Где именно возникает ошибка?

Comment: В приведенном выше коде нигде не встречается переменной `$AllDuels` где название этой переменной начинается с большой `A`.